# Can you edit aspx html content

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, visual-studio, iis

**Is is possible to edit the raw html content of a deployed .aspx page without recompiling or redeploying?**

For example say I have a deployed .net 4.6 aspx website. If i give someone FTP access to the .aspx files on the server can that person edit and update the layout of html elements without recompiling?

This might occur when a website is deployed onto a web host and a 3rd party contractor is requested to help improve the gui without being giving full access to the .sln file [eg c#\wcf\classes etc..].

Comment: Yes. But not recommended becouse changes are only on server.

Comment: In general, yes. The views are usually compiled (and cached) by the server, at least unless you explicitly precompiled them (in which case there would be no `aspx` files).

Comment: It is possible for sure.

Comment: if the use has access to where the .aspx files are being hosted this can be done but I personally think that this is a developers / support nightmare start looking at how to utilize a repository it will save your life in the long run plus how are you even keeping backup's of any of the original changes vs the edited file changes.. very poor practice / approach if you allow others to do this.. good luck

Comment: @MethodMan I have a svn repo, just dont want to give access to third party if they can just make changes on a test server and then we can merge them back in when they are completed.

Comment: why don't you have the 3rd Party send you the files then you can test the changes locally vs giving them direct access.. still a bad approach in my opinion especially if you own that domain space.. you need to take control not the other way around

Comment: @MethodMan if its just a test server which is publically facing it seems simple enough to just give them ftp access to certain folders.

Comment: just give it a try and see what happens it's your test server.. but once everything runs amuck, then perhaps you will look back and think, "Wow maybe I should have done things differently" this is a source control nightmare especially if they are not checking in the changes prior to promoting..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, this is possible.

.aspx files are not precompiled (unless you specifically say so, in which case you won't see them on the server).

One thing to keep in mind is that every time you change an .aspx-file, it will be recompiled the first time it's requested. Also after a number of changes (I belive this to be 20), the application pool will restart.

These page recompilations and apppool reboots could impact performance on your site.

Apart from that the usual guidelines apply and I would advise not to do this:

- the changes won't be synced back to your local repository
- You have little control or testing over the changes
- You have no backups of these changes

Answer (score 1):

It seems it should be possible to edit deployed aspx files, just to be aware the changes will not show up in the solution file which was used to deploy them but only be visible on the device where the edits occurred.

Answer (score 0):

yes, according to my experience, we can change .aspx, .cshtml, .html, .css and any image file in the host server if we have access to that server. Solution do not need to be compiled to change all these files because we upload directly these files on the host server. So for any change on these file either on our local machine or on host server, we can just copy and paste file from either location using remote connection to synchronize manually.

Only For all .cs file we only upload a dll file so solution need to be recompiled before uploading for any changes of class file.

So, if third party make any changes on host file like .apsx, .css. image file then these can be copied to the local machine directly to override the old one and checkin to the repository.